Installing NVIDIA graphics drivers causes Ubuntu 22.04 laptop to hang up while rebooting
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 laptop with a Quadro T1000 Mobile (NVIDIA Corporation) graphics card and am running into some issues while trying to install the correct NVIDIA drivers.
The first route I tried was to run sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, which seemed to work ok until I went to reboot my laptop after the installation. While rebooting, it got stuck on the pre-sign-in loading screen for hours until I went into recovery mode and ran the following commands to get it unstuck:
sudo apt purge ~nnvidia
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install system76-driver-nvidia

(Following advice here: https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/ though my laptop was getting stuck pre-login, not during login as mentioned in the article).
After getting back into my laptop, I tried again to install the drivers using this command: sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 and then tried rebooting the system and similarly, it hung up at the pre-login loading screen (and I had to follow the same steps described above to fix it so that I could log in).
I'm trying to get my graphics card drivers installed so I can run TensorFlow with my GPU, but have not been able to so far due to these issues. Just wondering if anyone might have some advice on what I'm doing wrong / what I could do differently to install these drivers correctly without messing up my system? Thanks for considering this question, I really appreciate it!

From your question it says sudo apt install system76-driver-nvidia  It appears you just installed this driver? If so you would need to remove and or purge it before trying to install a different driver.

@David Oh that's a good point, thank you for the feedback -- do you think trying to install the new driver overtop the old one would cause the hang-up during reboot?

Installing a second driver does not work. It does not remove the first one.
